# deleting items from a dictionary with a given list

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary, that has keys of the form ...

```
d = { 'x1' : (.....) , 'x2' : (......) ,'x3' : (.......) .....}
```

Suppose I have a list of values which contain some keys of the above dictionary.
let's say

```
l = ['x2','x3'..]
```

How do I delete the keys from `d`, which are given in `l`.
P.S. One `for` loop should suffice for this, but I am looking for better methods.
Something which uses list comprehension.

Comment: Why would you use a list-comprehension for this? You're not building a list here. A simple for-loop with `del` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Please do not downvote any further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `del`:

```
for k in l:
   del d[k]
```

Also, it's good idea to check, does element exists:

```
for k in l:
    if k in d:
         del d[k]
```

But simpler, to catch exception:

```
for k in l:
    try:
        del d[k]
    except KeyError:
        print 'No such key', k
```

And I recommend you to use [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

If you want to use comprehension:

```
[d.pop(k, None) for k in l]
```